# Filter observableArrayList base on a ChoiceBox selection

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a observableArrayList inflate with data from a DDBB. Each item of list has a Date property. I use a TableView to show observableArrayList data.

```
datos = observableArrayList();
datos.addAll(new TablaDAO().obtenItems()); //Get all items without any filter (I show this by default)
```

By default, users view all items, but I have a ChoiceBox where users can select a period (for example, last 30 days) and base on user's selection, the table only 
show rows which date is minor than 30 days.

```
chFiltrar.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        if (newValue.intValue() == 0) { //30 days
            //I need to show only items where date<last 30 days
        } else if (newValue.intValue() == 2) { //All days
            //This option works well because I show all items
        }
    });
```

I find answers related to use FilteredList but most cases are to filter based on a keyword search no from a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `FilteredList` is the right way. You'll do something like

```
datos = observableArrayList();
datos.addAll(new TablaDAO().obtenItems()); //Get all items without any filter (I show this by default)
FilteredList<Date> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(datos);
table.setItems(filteredList);
```

and then

```
chFiltrar.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        if (newValue.intValue() == 0) { //30 days
            //I need to show only items where date<last 30 days
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            filteredList.setFilter(date -> {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(date);
                return now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -30).before(date);
            });
        } else if (newValue.intValue() == 2) { //All days
            //This option works well because I show all items
            filteredList.setFilter(date -> true);
        }
    });
```

I would strongly recommend rewriting your code to use the new `java.time` API instead of the old `java.util.Date` and `Calendar` classes.

Comment: Ok, I like your answer, but I have a similar case whith other table view. In these case, I fill table rows but date is inside a set of objects. Example:

I get a list of items, inside each item I have a set of other items which have a date property. How can I access to that if is possible?

Comment: The parameter to the function you pass to `setFilter` is the item in the table's items list. So you can call any method on that that's defined in that class. It would be easier to answer if you posted the class you are using to represent the data in the table.